Get all french departement codes including Corsica
I want to get all departement in France. They can be count from 1 to 97, except for Corsica which is 2A and 2B.
I made this query that well get all numbers (except Corsica):
WITH RECURSIVE dep as (
       SELECT 1 as id
    UNION ALL
       SELECT id + 1 FROM dep WHERE id < 99
)

But now, I want to replace the "20" by "2A" and "2B". I tried to do this:
WITH RECURSIVE dep as (
       SELECT 1 as id
    UNION ALL
       SELECT id + 1 FROM dep WHERE id < 99
    UNION ALL
       SELECT '2A'
    UNION ALL
       SELECT '2B'
)

But I get this error: #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2B'
Here is what I want:



id




1


2


3


[omitted output ...]


17


18


19


2A


2B


21


22


...



How can I fix it?

Can you share more details, like the data from the table and the expected output?

@NicoHaase there is no input data, the recursive method works alone, I'll give you the expected output

What do you mean by "works alone"? A common installation of MariaDB does not even hold any table called dep, so it's impossible for others to reproduce the problem based on the current information

This question shouldn't have been closed. The CTE is 100% self-sufficient and produces a result set. The desired results explain the output. The question is clear and answerable.

The question was closed before I could answer, but here's one method... with recursive dep as (SELECT 1 as id UNION ALL SELECT id + 1 FROM dep WHERE id < 99) select cast(id as char) as id from dep where id <> 20 union select '2A' union select '2B'.

@NicoHaase Look again. The recursive cte runs all on its own and produces a result set.

@JNevill you're right, I've misread the code

@Isolated That's close, but two issues: 1) The two additional rows will not appear at the intended position in the result, but at the end after all other rows. 2) Use UNION ALL rather than UNION for better performance.

@JonasMetzler Thanks, wasn't sure if the sort was important, but understood.

@JonasMetzler Neither route will guarantee row order in the output. The ordering is just an artifact of the logic that it stays consistent every time you run it. If ordering is super important, than I would introduce an ORDER BY clause to both solutions so that it's clear to both the RDBMS and anyone else that encounters this code that the order is intended and explicit.

@JNevill Yes, sure, without ORDER BY, the sort of the result is never safe.

You can create a new derived table via a cte or subquery that holds your translated values, and then join that into your recursive cte result set:
WITH RECURSIVE dep as (
       SELECT 1 as id
    UNION ALL
       SELECT id + 1 FROM dep WHERE id < 99
)
, id_translation AS
(
  SELECT 20 as id, '2A' as alt_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, '2B'
)
SELECT COALESCE(idt.alt_id, dep.id) as id 
FROM dep
  LEFT OUTER JOIN id_translation idt 
     ON dep.id = idt.id


+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
| 6  |
| 7  |
| 8  |
| 9  |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
| 2A |
| 2B |
| 21 |
| 22 |
| .. |
+----+


Your CTE is generating an integer, so you can cast. Here's one method if the sort is of no matter.
with recursive dep as (
 SELECT 1 as id 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT id + 1 
 FROM dep 
 WHERE id < 99
) 
select cast(id as char) as id 
from dep 
where id <> 20 
union select '2A' 
union select '2B'


No need CTE :
SELECT seq
FROM seq_1_to_95
WHERE seq != 20

UNION VALUES ('2A'), ('2B')


and where does the seq_1_to_95 comes from?

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/

Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it
